# how to create my own sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ObjectPage

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to make my own Object Page for Smart template using UI5.

I tried using extensions, but it injects my custom view to existing objectpage,
but i want to add my own custom object page. 
using smart template for sap.suite.ui.generic.template.ListReport.

Comment: I try to understand the issue.
Could you please describe a little bit more in detail what you are trying to achieve?
Object Page contains header, navigation bar and content area.
Which of these do you want to extend?
There are many possibilities with Object Page.
Do you want to add new features to the object page?

Answer (score 1):

The help states that you can completely replace the object page with your own by specifying your own custom component. You would then be free to code it up however you like.

See here: https://sapui5.ap1.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/7e6e86984e6846bb8cfdfd3efb4d3e4b